# How to convert PDT time on a web page to the browsers local time?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I am trying to convert several dates and times that are in Pacific Daylight Time on a web page in the following format `04/29/2016 07:22:11` to the browsers local time or GMT

I am using a browser extension that runs javascript on a web page after it has loaded.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: You should manually parse the parts to create a date for that date and time using UTC methods, then add the PDT offset to the UTC hours. The host system will then work out what the "local" date and time is based on system settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should manually parse the string, then use UTC methods to create a Date and subtract the time zone offset. That will set the Date's time value to the equivalent in UTC. Then the host system will automatically apply host settings to output "local" values.

However, the problem with the string you're using is that there is no attached offset, so other than you knowing that it's -07:00, there's nothing in the string to confirm that. It's also ambiguous in regard to month and date order.

The following function does the job, it assumes that the time is in 24 hour format.

```js
/* Parse string in M/D/Y h:m:s format and apply an offset
** e.g. 04/29/2016 07:22:11 and offset -7
** @param {string} s      - date and time string in format M/D/Y h:m:s format
** @param {number} offset - UTC offset in hours of supplied date and time
**                          e.g. -7 (-07:00), 5.5 (+05:30)
** @returns {Date} date for supplied date and time adjusted for offset
*/
function toLocalFromOffset(s, offset) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(b[2], b[0]-1, b[1], b[3], b[4], b[5]));
  d.setUTCMinutes(d.getUTCMinutes() - offset * 60);
  return d;
}

var date = '04/29/2016 07:22:11';
var offsetHours = -7;
document.write('Date: ' + date + '<br>' +
               'Offset: ' + offsetHours + '<br>' +
               'Local date and time: ' + toLocalFromOffset(date, offsetHours));
```